# MYSQL complex IF NOT EXIST SELECT INSERT CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement, select, insert

I am making an attempt at writing a MySql conditional statement which then runs a set of commands, I keep coming up with error but enable to understand the issue. I have used recommendations from different topics here but still have no success, my last resort will be to run all queries individually which won't be efficient.

The code below has been edited to not include the if condition but I now have a variable assigning error

```
$SQL1 = "INSERT INTO members (first, last, email )
        VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email');
        SET @USER_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO babylon (user_id, crew )
        VALUES (@USER_ID, '$crew');

        INSERT INTO movement (badge, date)
        VALUES (@USER_ID, NOW())
        SET @BADGE_ROOM_CODE = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO messages (thread_id, sender_id)
        VALUES (@BADGE_ROOM_CODE, '@USER_ID')";

        $SQL2 = "SELECT id AS USER_ID FROM members WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1
        SET @USER_ID = USER_ID;

        INSERT INTO movement (badge, date)
        VALUES (@USER_ID, NOW())
        SET @BADGE_ROOM_CODE = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        INSERT INTO messages (thread_id, sender_id)
        VALUES (@BADGE_ROOM_CODE, @USER_ID)";

if(!$query_exists) { mySQLQuery($SQL2); } else { mySQLQuery($SQL1); }
```

Comment: If conditional statements are only allowed in stored programs(procedures,functions,triggers events)

Comment: I tried it without the if statement but seem to have an issue with the variable assignment

Comment: If you are building a statement to run through dynamic sql only 1 sql statement is allowed , multiple statements are not.

Comment: Thanks, I will run them individually.